# Volley is not working when loading from Xampp local server

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I created network application using **Volley library**

When i loading **JSON URL** from live server it work properly

But when i copy this **PHP** project from live server to local Server like **Xampp** and change **URL** parameter

`Response.ErrorListener()` method will be called, and nothing loaded .

Comment: check your local url and port number . also change the Db credentials in your php file

Comment: i checked it and my php file did not use database.my local server used port 80 and url is http://localhost:80/example.json. i tested it in browser its ok

Comment: print your errorTrace

Comment: E/MyError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: put your url like localhost/127.0.0.1:80 also check same url in brower

Comment: can you show your url ?

Comment: i test this http://localhost/example.json and this http://127.0.0.1/example.json

Comment: try http://127.0.0.1:80/example.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112776/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-j-and-abbas-nikzad).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of All you Have to get your Computer IP, in order to get it follow these steps:

1- click the Start Menu.

2- select Run.

3- type **cmd** into the box and click the OK button.

4- at the prompt, type **ipconfig**  and press Enter.

5- the information about your IP Address will be displayed like this

[IPV4 Address](http://www.howtofindmyipaddress.com/how-to-find-my-ip-address-pc.gif)

Second, Change the URL inside Your android Application to this IPV4 Address.for example : **"localhost/test/index.php"**

**"192.168.**.**/test/index.php"**

Answer (score 0):

I sloved my problem

Because i'm using **virtual machine** in **local** and the server is on **local**  too i must use the IP address of virtual machine connection to my system :

So i must use 192.168.56.1 instead 127.0.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After running ipconfig command there will be this option:-

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
>     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . : fe80::4d7:a9a5:fe9b:4866%2
>     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.173.2
>     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Replace localhost with the ipv4 address in your volley url.